# How to clear the ODP.NET connection pool on connection errors?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, ado.net, connection-pooling, odp.net

I'm using NHibernate and ODP.NET to connect to a Oracle 11g database. Of course there can be connection errors (network failure, DB down, ...). I'm handling all these exceptions in my code, so no problem there. But of course the user can retry his actions (maybe it was just a short network failure), and there comes my problem:

ODP.NET is using connection pooling by default. No problem with that usually, but when the user retries an action after a connection error, NHibernate gets an invalid (pooled) connection from ODP.NET. The user has to retry it multiple times (until the pool is empty) to get it working again.

Of course I can disable connection pooling in ODP.NET, but I'd like to avoid that. I've also read about a setting that checks the connection to the DB for each returned connection from the pool, but this adds an additional round trip to each connection which I'd like to avoid too.

Is there any way to configure ODP.NET to automatically clear the connection pool when any connection throws an connection exception?

Comment: I'd really like to know how to resolve this situation.  It seems like there is no good way to deal with it as the connection pool ends up with bad connections in it and trying to drill down to the actual Oracle connection that nhibernate uses to call ClearAllPools doesn't really work either.  The other issue is that replicating this situation for the purposes of debugging is a huge pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use odac (odp) **11g**, you have setting Validate Connection for your pool. It can validate the connection before you use it.

> The **Validate Connection** attribute validates connections coming out of the pool. This attribute should be used only when absolutely necessary, because it causes a round-trip to the database to validate each connection immediately before it is provided to the application. If invalid connections are uncommon, developers can create their own event handler to retrieve and validate a new connection, rather than using the Validate Connection attribute. This generally provides better performance.

If it will not be good enough - you can try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featConnecting.htm#i1006393) document from oracle.

> Connection Pool Management
>
> ODP.NET connection pool management provides explicit connection pool
>   control to ODP.NET applications. Applications can explicitly clear
>   connections in a connection pool.
>
> Using connection pool management, applications can do the following:
>
> Note: These APIs are not supported in a .NET stored procedure. Clear
>   connections from connection pools using the **ClearPool** method.
>
> Clear connections in all the connection pools in an application
>   domain, using the **ClearAllPools** method.
>
> When connections are cleared from a pool, ODP.NET repopulates the pool
>   with new connections that have at least the number of connections set
>   by Min Pool Size in the connection string. New connections do not
>   necessarily mean the pool will have valid connections. For example, if
>   the database server is down when ClearPool or ClearAllPools is called,
>   ODP.NET creates new connections, but these connections are still
>   invalid because they cannot connect to the database, even if the
>   database comes up a later time.
>
> It is recommended that ClearPool and ClearAllPools not be called until
>   the application can create valid connections back to the database.
>   .NET developers can develop code that continuously checks whether or
>   not a valid database connection can be created and calls ClearPool or
>   ClearAllPools once this is true.

Also, may be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845559/odp-net-connection-pooling-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-used) will help you.

**Update**:
As pointed by @MPelletier, for oracle 12 [the link is different](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT174).

Comment: As stated in my question I already read about this setting. But an additional round trip for each connection is not something I'm willing to pay for the rare case of an connection error. While I would prefer automatic clearing of the connection pool it seems like this isn't possible. Therefore I'll accept the solution to call `ClearPool` myself.

Comment: The first link is dead. The equivalent for Oracle 12 is here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT174

Comment: From your answer I indirectly got what I need: use [`OracleConnection.ClearPool(connection)` or `OracleConnection.ClearAllPools()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleConnectionClass.htm#ODPNT793). It is worth mentioning them directly. (Your answer does not state explicitly they are static members of `OracleConnection` class.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should avoid trying to manipulate the connection pool for any ADO.NET provider (and also WCF channels - an aside). If you application needs to be resilient in the face of underlying data errors (e.g. timeouts, broken connections in pool, etc.) then you should implement the appropriate level of transaction to ensure data integrity and retry logic to re-execute the failed operation.

Comment: My application is already working with transactions and allows the user to retry the operation. The problem is just that even if the user retries it after an connection error, the operation still fails even if the network connection is repaired. It seems like ODP.NET is giving me an connection back that timed out while it was in the connection pool.

Comment: Is there a firewall between the app and the DB? I know this sounds like a *canned* question, but I have seen serious oddities like this when some network device (firewall, switch or routers) is behivaing agressively and snapping shut connections even though the pool thinks they are still open. This comes from experience with SSA, DoD, and other government setups with huge Oracle and .NET investments. My 2 cents.

Comment: No, nothing other than some switches. Not even a router.