# C# WinForm Oracle sessions hangs after connection closed

Tags: c#, winforms, session, oracle10g, system.data.oracleclient

I'm using multiple connections in different methods, but when I close the connection, the connection sessions hangs in database sessions as inactive until I terminate the .exe file. I'm using connections in using statement like:

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constring))
{
con.Open();
}
```

And I also tried to close and dispose the connection manually and use **OracleConnection.ClearPool(con)** and **OracleConnection.ClearAllPools()** but none of them works.

the reference im using:
**System.Data.OracleClient version 2.0.0.0**

connection string
**Data Source = ip/db; User Id = user; Password=pw;**

Comment: This isn't really an answer but we had a very similar issue where I work recently. One of the other devs has added this to our connection string and things seem to have improved. I'm by no means an expert in this but it might help you out too. "Min Pool Size = 0; Max Pool Size = 16; Incr Pool Size = 2; Decr Pool Size = 1; Validate Connection = False; Connection Lifetime = 0;" Just add that into your connection string and see how it goes.

Comment: Incr Pool Size, Decr Pool Size and Validate Connection unsupported keyword :(

Comment: My mistake I missed that you're still using  System.Data.OracleClient. This is deprecated nowadays. Have you tried using the newer ODAC adaptor? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

Comment: I would love to but I have to use net 2.0 framework and I guess 2.0.0.0 is the newest adaptor for it. at least by Microsoft. sry, I forgot to mention that I'm using net 2.0 and thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is normal because if you `Dispose();` a connection the ConnectionPool from Oracle doesn't really destroy the connection but set the status to 'free'. So the next time you open a connection, you don't really open a new connection, you just look for a 'free' connection in your ConnectionPool and use this one. If no free Connection exists, a new one will be created.

This behaviour garants you a better performance because Open/Close Connections cost much afford.

If you use:

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constring)) 
{
}
```

or

```
con.Close();
```

This is the same as you use `Dispose();`. Using just make sure that the Dispose is called on the end of your using block. That's why using only works on objects which implement IDisposable.

So far ok...But why doesn't `OracleConnection.ClearAllPools()`close the connections? It does but Oracle directly create a new Connection, so that your ConnectionPool is filled up to your MinPool-Size. This is the reason why BigTallJosh's code:

> "Min Pool Size = 0; Max Pool Size = 16; Incr Pool Size = 2; Decr Pool
>   Size = 1; Validate Connection = False; Connection Lifetime = 0;

stop this behaviour. A Min Pool Size of 0 will stop automatic creation of new connections.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726499/how-to-clear-the-odp-net-connection-pool-on-connection-errors) you can find a good explanation about `ClearAllPools();` Method.

So to finally answer your question. Set the `MinPoolSize=0` and after that call `connection.ClearAllPools();`. This should work.

Comment: **Clearpool()** and **Clearpools()** worked after changing current reference with **Oracle.DataAccess 2.102.2.20** but now i will have some oracle client issues on some computers :( thx for your effort

Comment: @trksyln Your welcome. Interesting that this version got an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't really understand what our other dev did to make ours nicer but this explains it clearly! +1